# how can i get parallel data entered into a shift register circuit

Tags: shift-register

If i want to use a shift register circuit to input several binary bits at once (parallel data transfer), and then output the bits one at a time over a single line (serial data transfer). describe how can i get parallel data entered into a shift register circuit knowing the fact that the shift registers are constructed with D-type flip-flops.

Answer (score 1):

The ’HC165 ([datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/sn74hc165.pdf)) is a classic parallel-in serial-out shift register (PISO).

The 74HC165 is a 8-bit parallel-load shift register.
Several of them can be cascaded to load any amount of data on a single load pulse, and then shift out that data one bit at a time.

The datasheet shows exactly how it works:

It's a string of D flip-flops with the Q output of each one connected to the D input of the next one in the chain.

As EM Fields described,
to get the parallel data entered into the register, some external circuit pulses the LOAD pin low, which internally uses the SET and RESET inputs of each D flipflop
in such a way that the "1"s or "0"s on the external data input pins are copied into the corresponding D flipflop.

After that initial load, typically the external circuit holds the LOAD pin high (so the external data input pins are ignored), and then pulses the CLK pin. Each pulse shifts all the stored bits over by one, making the next bit available out the Q output pins.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a parallel in serial out shift register. If is query is with regard to HDL you will require a load control signal to loading the data in the shift register and when load goes low you will be performing the normal shift operation(Either left shift or right shift as per your needs)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it in at least a couple of ways; one being to use 2:1 muxes on the "D" inputs and the other to use the SET and RESET inputs.

In the first method the muxes accept the broadside loads on one input, the "Q" output of a flop is connected to the other mux input and the mux output is connected to the "D" input of the next flop in the string.

In use, the muxes are switched to input the broadside load, a single clock pulse is issued to enter the data into the flops, then the  muxes are switched to connect the "Q" outputs to the following "D" inputs, and enough clocks issued to shift the data through the register.

In the second method, the "Q"s and "D"s are connected in a series string and the SET or  RESET input of each stage is asserted in order to cause its "Q" output to be in the state required.  Thereafter, the SEts and RESETs are de-asserted and the clock allowed to shift the data through the register.